# accessing a USB drive in python for a beginner

Tags: python, pyusb

level student doing my second year project in computing and have decide to try and create a utility that access the USB drives and return a percentage value of how much space the different files and folders take up of the USB in a GUI(code for GUI).

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
def select():
    sf = "value is %s" % var.get()
    root.title(sf)
    # optional
    color = var.get()
    root['bg'] = color
root = Tk()

# use width x height + x_offset + y_offset (no spaces!)
root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (1000, 600, 10, 10))
root.title("USB scanner")
frame1=Frame(root)
frame1.pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)
var = StringVar(root)
# initial value

var.set('select drive')
choices = ['', '', '', '','', '']
option = OptionMenu(frame1, var, *choices)
option.pack(side=LEFT)
button = Button(frame1, text="Scan selected drive", command=select)
button.pack(side=LEFT, padx=30, pady=30)

root.mainloop()
```

i have installed pyUSB-1.0.0a2 and libopenusb-1.1.11 i keep getting the back end is not available error i have checked DLL. if i'm honest i don't know what i'm doing to much so any basic help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following program should help to get you pointed in the right direction:

```
from tkinter import *
from shutil import disk_usage

class Sizer(Frame):

    @classmethod
    def main(cls):
        NoDefaultRoot()
        root = Tk()
        root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(200, 100))
        root.resizable(False, False)
        root.title('Drive Information')
        widget = cls(root)
        widget.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
        root.mainloop()

    def __init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, cnf, **kw)
        self.selection = StringVar(self)
        self.menu = OptionMenu(self, self.selection, 'A:\\', 'B:\\', 'C:\\')
        self.menu.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
        self.button = Button(self, text='Scan the drive', command=self.scan)
        self.button.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
        self.display = Label(self)
        self.display.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=NSEW)

    def scan(self):
        disk = self.selection.get()
        try:
            information = disk_usage(disk)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            self.display['text'] = 'Disk {!r} cound not be found'.format(disk)
        else:
            self.display['text'] = 'Used: {}\nFree: {}'.format(
                information.used, information.free)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Sizer.main()
```